# How do I pass button state and variable onto another page in wordpress?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, shopping-cart

I've created a wordpress site, and have 4 buttons displaying different $ amounts.
I want to save which of those buttons gets selected.
When I click the submit button, I want it to use that number.

```
        <h2>Amount   </h2>      
        <a href="#" role="button">
                    $51.00
                </a>
        <a href="#" role="button">
                    $110.00
                </a>
        <a href="#" role="button">
                    $65.00
                </a>
        <a href="#" role="button">
                    $278.00
                </a>
        <a href="#" role="button">
                    Submit
                </a>
```

This is all I have, and I don't know my next step.

Comment: as per your code, no button will get selected. First of all no submit property for last button

Comment: How do I make it so it gets selected?

Comment: How about using and actual form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using an actual form?

```
<h2>Amount</h2>

<form action="" method="get">


    <input id="51" type="radio" name="amount" value="51">

    <label for="51">$51.00</label>


    <input id="110" type="radio" name="amount" value="110">

    <label for="110">$110.00</label>


    <input id="65" type="radio" name="amount" value="65">

    <label for="65">$65.00</label>


    <input id="278" type="radio" name="amount" value="278">

    <label for="278">$278.00</label>



    <input type="submit">


</form>
```

Here how you could style it:
https://jsbin.com/boxifiguqo/2/edit?html,css,output

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad i could help ;)

Comment: The only thing is if I have a second conditional? I found something similar. https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/UHLq7yuhwlTXnOUjRMwApmnWLQYRx4jXhmL7YyXU3RDDtQV09WQxzrZE7yvoF-XhgjsEuM-8lrjtvziX9yXdKFnYA5gcBsJ0eNsz0l8BvRzyUY7F32YWOq93lGQnvgEDBRS9GSNo

Comment: You should dig into HTML … HTML forms in general :/ … This is pretty basic stuff